# Clarification about Parent process writing message to Child process using simple pipe

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pipe, ipc

This is a C program where the Parent process tries to write a message to its child process using a simple pipe. The expected output is obtained.

According to the code, the parent calls wait() and waits until the child process exits(returns).

Also, the child process calls read(), which waits for something to be written through the other pipe end?

Thus, shouldn't both processes keep waiting for each other and cause a deadlock? How is it possible that the program works properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define MSGSIZE 16
char *msg1 = "Hello,Once";
char *msg2 = "Hello,Twice";
char *msg3 = "Hello,Thrice";
int main()
{
    char buff[MSGSIZE];
    int pi[2],pid,nbytes;
    if(pipe(pi) < 0) _exit(1);
    if((pid=fork()) > 0)
    {
        close(pi[0]);
        write(pi[1],msg1,MSGSIZE);
        write(pi[1],msg2,MSGSIZE);
        write(pi[1],msg3,MSGSIZE);
        close(pi[1]); 
        wait(NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        close(pi[1]);
        while((nbytes = read(pi[0],buff,MSGSIZE)) > 0) printf("%s\n",buff);
        printf("Reading Completed\n");
        close(pi[0]);
        if(nbytes != 0) _exit(2);
        
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `close(pi[1]); ` in the parent will cause the child `read` to return `EOF` once all data has been read out. At which point the child will exit and thus the parent's `wait` will unblock.

Comment: You code has another problem: To write the messages, there is an access beyond the strings because their size is not always MSGSIZE.

Comment: Got it.Tnx @kaylum